# How I can sort my entry that belong to 3 section on date?

Tags: entries, datetime, filter

```
{% set blog = craft.entries.section('blog').all() %}
{% set news = craft.entries.section('news').all() %}
{% set caseStudies = craft.entries.section('caseStudies').all() %}
{% set allEntries = blog|merge(news)|merge(caseStudies) %}
{% for entry in allEntries %}  
 <span>  
       {{entry.nameSection}} | {{entry.dateNews|date("F  d, Y")}}
</span>
<h3 class="title post-title">
      {{entry.title}}
</h3>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This would have to be done by creating a custom Twig Filter. You might want to check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42221062/2386328

Comment: Thanks, but this is my first meet with craft and I don't create that filter ((( Is there a simpler solution?

Answer (score 3):

Try chaining the sections together like:

```
{% set allEntries = craft.entries({
  section: ['blog', 'news', 'caseStudies']
}).orderBy('elements.dateCreated asc').all() %}
```

Then

```
{% for entry in allEntries %}  
   <span>  
       {{entry.nameSection}} | {{entry.dateNews|date("F  d, Y")}}
   </span>

   <h3 class="title post-title">
       {{entry.title}}
   </h3>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Happy to help! :)